# Checking multiple empty field in a form

Tags: php, forms

How can i check 2 text fields are empty with PHP.

Here is exactly what i want

there are 2 text fields in my form. I dont want the form to be submitted if both fields are empty. But if one of the text fields have a entered value form should get submitted.

I have tired this code but it wont submit if both fields values are entered.

```
if($_POST['inputOne'] == NULL AND $_POST['inputTwo'] == NULL )
    { 
        die('My Error Msg.');

    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: You want to use `OR` instead of `AND`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Fred -ii- (with edits to he's code) i have found an answer

```
if(empty($_POST['inputOne']) AND empty($_POST['inputTwo']))

{ 
        die('My Error Msg.');

}
```

If you dont use AND it will not look for both fields empty together instead it will look of each field separately.

Comment: Actually your awesome. Sorry for the delay to vote :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_POST['inputOne'] == NULL OR $_POST['inputTwo'] == NULL )
```

> *"But still this look for both fields to have a value. Adding value to one field will not post the form"*

Use the following then. It will check if one *or* both are empty.

```
if(empty($_POST['inputOne']) || empty($_POST['inputTwo'])){...}
```

instead of using `== NULL`

FYI: `||` is the same as using `OR`

- Consult: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

---

Or as you state in your answer: (*using `AND`*)

```
if(empty($_POST['inputOne']) && empty($_POST['inputTwo'])){...}
```

where `&&` is the same as `AND` - just another quick "FYI".

- It saves you a keystroke (wink)

Answer (score 0):

There should be an OR instead of the AND.

```
if($_POST['inputOne'] == NULL OR $_POST['inputTwo'] == NULL )
    { 
        die('My Error Msg.');

    }
```

**EDIT**: If `OR` doesn't suffice try:

```
if(empty($_POST['inputOne']) || empty($_POST['inputTwo']))
    { 
        die('My Error Msg.');

    }
```

Comment: But still this look for both fields to have a value. Adding value to one field will not post the form